# What could prevent a window from being displayed in foreground?

Tags: winapi, modal-dialog, showwindow, setforegroundwindow

What could prevent a dialog from being displayed modally in foreground in some circumstances?

A process (KeePass.exe) owns a hidden window. A global shortcut (CTRL+A) displays a dialog in **foreground**. This is done using the DoModal method. And it works.

However, in some circumstances which I do not know, the follwing happens: The window appears in the taskbar and only after clicking on it, it is shown. I created a plugin for KeePass which overwrites the WndProc and waits for a certain WM_COPYDATA message. If this message arrives, the dialog is shown using DoModal. However, in this case it is only displayed in the taskbar and not shown in foreground.

The WM_COPYDATA message is sent from a different process, but this should not matter right? What can be a reason for that?

I am struggling for so long on this, it's so weird that's even difficult to explain the problem.

I tried issuing SetForegroundWindow(hKeePassWindow) before showing the dialog but no change.

Comment: Without any code this is tricky. Can you make an SSCCE.

Comment: I know unfortunately :( I thought providing code but there is so much in between since it is just a plugin for a large application (KeePass). Fortunately everything is Open Source. So I could add references and line numbers to the code if that would help.

Comment: You should make a simple repro. Or debug the problem yourself. Realistically nobody is going to take the time to set up a complex build environment.

Comment: Ok thank you; give me some time I will try to create repo as small as possible.